# Google drive api загрузка .docx и конвертация в гугл док v2

Tags: java, spring-mvc, google-api, google-docs-api

Необходимо загружать файлы через API и открывать их в новом окне web - app для редактирования. Если загружать через интерфейс гугла (Google Drive), то все выходит. Проверил `getMimeType` файлов, которые залил через интерфейс и через API:

- у того, который залил через API - `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document`
- через интерфейс - `application/vnd.google-apps.document`, т.е. при загрузке через интерфейс происходит конвертирование файла, как это сделать через API?

Для получения ссылки для встраивания в `iframe` использую

```
file.getAlternateLink()
```

Код, которым делаю добавление файла через API:

```
public  String mainProjects(@RequestParam MultipartFile file, Model model) {//заходит файл .docx 
        File body = new File();
        body.setTitle(file.getOriginalFilename());
        body.setDescription("");
        java.io.File fileContent = convert(file);
        FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent(null, fileContent);
        try {
            File file2 = drive.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();
            String id = file2.getId();
            model.addAttribute("frame",drive.files().get(id).execute().getAlternateLink());
            System.out.println(drive.files().get(id).execute().getAlternateLink());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occured: " + e);
        }
```

Comment: вдруг кому будет полезно, - решил через добавление body.setMimeType("application/vnd.google-apps.document");

Comment: Оформите это ответом, пожалуйста.